# Как реализовать проверку строки sql на наличие входных данных?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, sqlite

Хочу реализовать систему регистрации и входа в аккаунт, но возникла проблема в  проверке таблицы на наличие записей. нужно шаблонно подставить в условия определенные значения, но не могу разобраться как правильно.

```
try:
    check = cur.execute('''SELECT name, password FROM user WHERE name=? password=?''', self.login, self.password)
    if check:
        pass
except IOError:
    pass
```

Comment: в качестве параметров нужно передавать кортеж или список - `(self.login, self.password)` или `[self.login, self.password]`

Comment: Вероятно ошибка в SQL-запросе: `... WHERE name=? AND password=?`

Comment: Зачем выбирать имя и пароль? достаточно `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`. Если пришёл ноль - записи нет, 1 - запись есть, другое значение - ошибки в БД или проблемы с сервером. Что приятно - сам по себе такой запрос никогда не приведёт к ошибке NOT FOUND.

Answer (score 2):

Для функции `execute` на месте аргумента необходимо указывать `%s`, а не `?`.
Аргументы необходимо передавать кортежем или списком.
Но `execute` не возвращает данные, поэтому после запроса нужно получить их с помощью `cur.fetchone()` или `cur.fetchall()`.

Таким образом правильный запрос будет выглядеть как:

```py
cur.execute('''SELECT name, password FROM user WHERE name=%s password=%s''', [self.login, self.password])
user = cur.fetchone() # None или кортеж с данными
```

Comment: можно чуть подробнее об второй строке? какие именно данные она должна принимать и как она должна быть связана с первой строкой c sql запросом?

Comment: Дело в том, что `execute` работает не так как вы ожидаете. Она **НЕ** возвращает никаких данных, это не интуитивно, но это так. Для получения данных используется `fetchone`. `fetchone` вернет имя и пароль, потому что это указано в select запросе. Вместо этого можно написать `COUNT(*)` как писал Akina, тогда вам вернется количество записей для которых выполнилось условие.